# How do I group together radio buttons that are in a custom control?

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0, radio-button, custom-controls, grouping

I have a custom control (not component) based off a radio button that has a fancy label that will glow green when the label is selected, and black when it is not to give better visual feedback and because why not.

To confirm my fears I dropped a bunch on a form and ran it and, sure enough, they weren't considered "grouped together" in that I could activate all of them and none of the others deactivated.

How am I to be able to make it so that each of these controls will be part of a "Special Radio Button Group" and behave as a normal radio button would?

Comment: WinForms?  Did you Inherit from RadioButton?

Comment: I did not. If I had I know I could make it work but I am using a special label (gLabel) over the standard label and do not know how to lay that over the standard label. That would probably be an ideal solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found "A" solution. I don't know if it's an IDEAL solution but it works.

I had had the object function off of looking for the "CheckedChanged" event. The problem is that this fires whether it was done manually or programatically.
Solution? Use the "Clicked" event. But not just on the button, on the entire thing.

So what we get is this:

```
namespace Pieces{
public partial class ucGraphicLabelRadioButton : UserControl{
    private event EventHandler _CheckedChanged;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the controls text.
    /// </summary>
    public override string Text{
        get{return this.lblTitle.Text;}
        set{lblTitle.Text = value;}
    }
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the checked state of the button.
    /// </summary>
    public bool Checked{
        get{return this.rbtnButton.Checked;}
        set{this.rbtnButton.Checked = value;}
    }

    public event EventHandler CheckedChanged{
        add{this._CheckedChanged += value;}
        remove{this._CheckedChanged -= value;}
    }

    public ucGraphicLabelRadioButton(){
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //This is where the fancy stuff happens...
    private void ToggleCheck(object sender, EventArgs e){
        this.lblTitle.GlowColor = Color.Green;
        bool FoundOtherChecked = false;
        this.Parent.Controls.OfType<ucGraphicLabelRadioButton>().Where(x => x.Checked && x != this).ToList().ForEach(x => {
            x.Checked = false;
            x.lblTitle.GlowColor = Color.Black;
            FoundOtherChecked = true;
        });

        if ((FoundOtherChecked && !this.Checked) || !this.Checked){
            this.Checked = !this.Checked;            
            this.lblTitle.GlowColor = this.rbtnButton.Checked ? Color.Green : Color.Black;
        }

        if (this._CheckedChanged != null)
            this._CheckedChanged(this, new EventArgs());
    }
}
```

}

The "ToggleCheck" event is tied to the RadioButton objects "Click" event as well as the labels "Click" event and the entire custom controls "Click" event so ideally clicking anywhere on the label will fire the event off.

When the object is toggled it runs a linq search for any object that is like itself in the parent control and grabs it ONLY if it's checked. Then, it unchecks it and sets the glow state to black.

The control also has an event that forwards any sort of event you want to tie to the radio buttons "CheckedChanged" event and then fires it.

I know that doing the whole

```
.ToList().ForEach(x => ...)
```

is total overkill since the search would only ever return a single object (or none in the case it was turning itself off) but it does work. Is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:** I had to make some changes since evidently when you click directly on the radio button, it becomes checked first THEN the clicked event fires. Also, to make sure they behave more like radio buttons and less like check boxes with radio-button like behavior, I.E.: The user can't click them off now. It checks to see if one was toggled on before toggling itself off.